# Algorithm for neuron activation order

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm developing a [JS library](https://github.com/wagenaartje/gynaptic) with the ability to create 'flexible' neural networks. Flexible meaning that they don't consist of layers, but merely of single neurons or neuron 'groups'.

I don't want to activate neurons layer by layer, as this does not give a lot of options for layer mutation/modification.

So i'm looking for an algorithm which decides the neuron activation order. Example of a neural net:

[image]
This quite a complex net. But I want to decide the activation order of this neural network with an algorithm, ofcourse I can figure it out myself, some of the correct orders are:

`1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10`

`1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6, 8, 7, 10, 9`

`3, 5, 8, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10`

**I need al agorithm which returns a possible activation order!** Any hints?
*(the algorithm is given the connections between neurons)*

---

But it get's more complex... say we have some short term memory:[image]

The algorithm should not take any connections that serve as memory into consideration. So these two added memory connections shouldn't alter the activation order!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply [topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) to the neural network, and pretend no memory connection exists while sorting.